# How to resolve $('.selector').flatpickr is not a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, flatpickr

I am using jquery 3.6 and flatpickr 4.6.9 in my project, but when I try to instantiate using my jquery selector, it gives me error saying `Uncaught TypeError: $datePlanted.flatpickr is not a function`. Below is the jquery and html code:

JQuery

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import flatpickr from 'flatpickr';

const $datePlanted = $('.plot-tree-form__date-planted-text')
$datePlanted.flatpickr({
      enableTime: false,
      dateFormat: 'Y-m-d'
    });
```

HTML

```
<div class="plot-tree-form__form-group plot-tree-form__date-planted">
 <label for="date-planted">
    Date Planted Here
    <input type="text" class="plot-tree-form__date-planted-text" name="date-planted" placeholder="Date here"/>
 </label>
</div>
```

According to flatpickr documentation, this should be working. How can I resolve this issue? I have been stuck on this for really long. Any help will be really appreciated.

Documentation - https://flatpickr.js.org/getting-started/

This is how I am importing jquery and flatpickr in my javascript file
[image]

Comment: 1) do you definitely have a `<script src=..flatpickr...`>?  2) is it definitely *after* your script src=jquery?  and 3) do you *definitely* **not** have another jquery script tag *after* your flatpickr script src?  This last one happens a lot when using a framework such as wordpress/asp.net-mvc that stuffs its own jquery at the foot of the body.

Comment: The most important part of your code is the part that includes the jquery and flatpickr libraries. You haven't included that part in the question, but that's almost certainly where the bug is.

Comment: Your code works fine as provided.  https://jsfiddle.net/6wars20y/   So it's likely an issue with the script tags.

Comment: I am using npm to download flatpickr, hence i imported in my javascript file after importing jquery, I have attached a screenshot in the question now

Comment: @ChrisLear I have edited the question and added in the code of how i am importing jquery and flatpickr along with a screenshot

Comment: @freedomn-m I have edited the question and added in more details as to how i am importing jquery and flatpickr along with a screenshot

Comment: How can I fix this issue? It still persists, I am importing jquery before flatpickr as shown in the screenshot in the question

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and my solution was this: **after** referencing JQuery, then reference **BOTH** the css **AND** the js files for flatpickr (one after another):

```
      <script src="path/to/JQuery"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/flatpickr.css"> 
      <script src="path/to/flatpickr.js"></script>
```

Then just:

```
<input class="calendar" type="text" placeholder="Select Date..">

<script>
    $(".calendar").flatpickr();
</script>
```